# Flickr Json different size

Tags: jquery, api, flickr

I'm building a custom widget for my site, fetching flickr photos. This code works fine, but I need to fetch the small size 320x240 instead of 240x180.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?ids=<?php print $flickrid; ?>lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
                      $.each(data.items, function(index, item){
                            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(".slides_container")
                      });
                    });
            });
```

It's currently fetching the "_m" size, what I need is the "_n", thank you.

Comment: Can you do a console.log(item,item.media) before $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(".slides_container") and post the output please?

Comment: What exactly should I enter in the console? I entered that entire line you've posted and this is what I've got:
>>> console.log(item,item.media) before $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(".slides_container")

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]  

...(item,item.media) before $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(".slides...

Don't think that's what you want me to do. Sorry, just new to JS.

Comment: You can't get the desired output via just entering the line via console. you have to add that line to you code before this line: $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(".slides_container") and then paste the output in your answer. It would be easier if you could post a test URL which makes debugging much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this sorted easily, must of been tired last night.

For anyone else looking for this, simply change

```
("src", item.media.m)
```

to

```
("src", item.media.m.replace('_m', '_n'))
```

_n being the size you wish to fetch.